# Search by dropdown with category name, products,article

Tags: magento-1.9, search

As i need to develop a search functionality with category names, Product, Article.
Is there any free extension or any custom development please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on Magento Connect https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=search&pl=0